# Warning for non optional in swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I have this code, i found in the net. I don't understand how to fix it, cause i have a warning from xcode, for non optionalexpression of type calendar used in a check for optionals

```
func dayOfWeek() -> Int? {
    if
        let cal: Calendar = Calendar.current,
        let comp: DateComponents = (cal as NSCalendar).components(.weekday, from: self) {
            return comp.weekday
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: "if let" is for unwrapping optionals. If a value is not an optional... then don't try to unwrap it with "if let". That's what the error message is saying.

Comment: Moritz' answer is corrrect. You are trying to safe unwrap a nonoptional value in the line If let cal: Calendar = Calendar.current.
This line is not returning a optional so you cannot unwrap it.
For more information see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: so i only have to delete the if statement? and it's safe?

Comment: If it's not an optional it means that it can't be nil so yes, it's safe.